# NSDictionary - Cannot Invoke "init"

Tags: swift

This is the code

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [user.username, image], forKeys: ["username", "image"])
```

I am getting the error

Cannot invoke "init" with an argument list type (objects: $T3, forKeys: $T7)

More code to show how user.username and image is created

```
let users = objects

                        for userId in self.arrayUserIds
                        {
                            let user = self.getUserFromUserId(userId as String, arrayUsers: users)

                            self.arrayUserFriends.addObject(user)

                            var query = PFQuery(className: "UserPhoto")
                            query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)

                            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
                                (NSArray objects, NSError error) -> Void in

                                if(objects.count != 0)
                                {
                                    let object = objects[objects.count - 1] as PFObject
                                    let theImage = object["imageData"] as PFFile

                                    let imageData:NSData    = theImage.getData()
                                    let image               = UIImage(data: imageData)


                                    let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [user.username, image], forKeys: ["username", "image"])
                                    self.arrayFriends.addObject(dictionary)

                                    self.chatTable.reloadData()
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: is image or user.username an optional?

Comment: no it's not optional

Comment: The above code is fine, if I replace your objects with objects I know to be good. - show the code that declares user.username and image

Comment: edited the question to show it @Woodstock

Comment: UIImage returns an Optional, that's your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIImage initialiser you are calling returns an Optional,

```
init?(data data: NSData)
```

**From the docs:**
*Return Value
An initialized UIImage object, or nil if the method could not initialize the image from the specified data.*

You need to force unwrap the Optional like this (note the **!** mark after *image*):

```
let dictionary = NSDictionary(objects: [user.username, image!], forKeys: ["username", "image"])
```

Comment: You really should check that the image is not nil and handle that error if it's not.